# MVC - SwingWorker with a long running process that should update the view

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, design-patterns, swingworker

**How to obtain separation of the View from model when using a SwingWorker  with a long running process that should send updates back to the controller ?**

- I can use the `SwingWorkers` `doInBackground()` to keep the EDT responsive by calling   e.g `model.doLongProcess()` from in there great!
- The issue I have is trying to get data back before the process is finished, to update the view with the progress..
- I know that I can get data back by using by using the `SwingWorkers` `publish()` method but this I think forces me to write the code for the `doLongProcess()` method within  `doInBackground()`.

---

For reference the MVC implementation I have a looks a little like this:

http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/structure/40mvc.html

```
/ structure/calc-mvc/CalcMVC.java -- Calculator in MVC pattern.
// Fred Swartz -- December 2004

import javax.swing.*;

public class CalcMVC {
    //... Create model, view, and controller.  They are
    //    created once here and passed to the parts that
    //    need them so there is only one copy of each.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CalcModel      model      = new CalcModel();
        CalcView       view       = new CalcView(model);
        CalcController controller = new CalcController(model, view);

        view.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have one Model Class which wraps a number of other classes together to a form simple interface for the controller.

I really don't want to have to move all/some/any of the code from these Classes into the controller - It doesn't belong there.

---

**Update:**

Here is the approach that I am taking - Its not the cleanest solution and It could be perceived as an abuse of `PropertyChangeSupport`.. on a semantic level.

Basically all the low-level classes that have long running methods will have a `propertyChangeSupport` field. The long running methods call the `firePropertyChange()` periodically to update on the status of the method and not necessarily to report the change of a property - that is what I mean by semantic abuse!.

Then the Model class which wraps the low level classes catches these events and issues its own highlevel `firePropertyChange` .. which the `controller` can listen for...

**Edit:**

To clarify, when I call firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);

- propertyName ---> I abuse the propertyName to represent a topicname
- oldValue =null
- newValue = the message that I want to broadcast

Then the PropertyChangeListener in the model or where ever can discern the message based on the topicname.

So Iv basically bent the system to use it like a publish-subscribe ....

---

I guess in place of the above method I could add a progress field to the lowlevel classes that gets updated, and then firePropertyChange based on that.. this would fall into line with how its supposed to be used.

Comment: Please see edit to my answer in response to your update.

Answer (score 4):

I think of the publish/process pair as *pushing* data from the SwingWorker into the GUI. Another way to pass information is by having the GUI or control *pull* the information out of the SwingWorker by using PropertyChangeSupport and PropertyChangeListeners. Consider

- giving your model a PropertyChangeSupport field,
- Giving it add and remove PropertyChangeListener methods
- Having it notify the support object of changes in state.
- Having the SwingWorker add a PropertyChangeListener to the model.
- Then having the SwingWorker notifying control or view of changes in the model's state.
- The SwingWorker could even use publish/process with the changed information from the model.

**Edit**
Regarding your update:

> Basically all the low-level classes that have long running methods will have a propertyChangeSupport field. The long running methods call the firePropertyChange() periodically to update on the status of the method and not necessarily to report the change of a property - that is what I mean by semantic abuse!.

I don't recommend that you do this. Understand that if the bound property being listened to does not change, none of the PropertyChangeListeners (PCLs) will be notified even if firePC() is called. If you need to poll a property, then I wouldn't use a PCL to do this. I would simply poll it, probably from outside of the class being polled.

Comment: +1 I like this pattern. But I wonder if this nasty to add a PropertyChangeSupport field to the low level modules that the model wraps. For example if I had a class for encoding mp3s that was used in the model would it be ok to add a PropertyChangeSupport field to the Mp3Encoder class?  I know I could just add a method in the model to add the listener.. I guess as long as the PropertyChangeSupport.. is supported accross the board i.e swing, swt, android it should be ok.

Comment: hmmmm .. regarding your update - I have already tried my method and it works. I don't bind to a property name - I have declared a number of static strings that represent topics , when I fire a property change,  I pass the topicname for  propertyName, null for the oldValue, and a message for the newValue parameter. From what I can see there is nothing forcing you to use a propertyName its just a string. I guess to use this system the way its supposed to be used I could just have a progress property that gets updated..

Comment: @volting don't quite understand who is listening to the propertyChanges

Comment: @kleopatra - the model listens to events produced by methods in the lowlevel objects. The model will produce events based on these which the controller will be listening for. Hope this makes sense. -See my updated answer - it "might" make more sense now, I hope.

Comment: @volting hmmm ... and where does the SwingWorker come into play? In controller listening for model or no worker at all, controller simply pulling the data and pushing it with invokeLater to the view on  receiving the event?

Comment: @kleopatra The swingWorker is in the controller. It doensn't implement the PropertyChangeListner yet - Im adding that at the minute,  it will be listening for the model..

Comment: @volting but then, the model is already changed (that's the contract of the propertyChangeEvent) _and_ did so off the EDT. Now if the view is anything near a JSomething showing the model, the EDT rule would have been violated ... probably missing something in your setup :-)

Comment: @kleopatra - Yes Im updating my view components in the propertyChange() handler method..  your right this will be outside EDT. I could call publish() in propertyChange() and pass it the info.. so that the process() method can then appropriately update the GUI.. (Although Im not sure that this is safe either) -I think is starting to get ugly -Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, in my `SwingWorker` I'd create a public `publish` method, and pass the instance of my `SwingWorker` to the long running Model method.  That way the model pushes updates to the control (`SwingWorker`), which then pushes to the View.

Here's an example - I threw everything into one file (for simplicity of running), but I'd imagine normally you'd have separate files/packages for these things.

**EDIT**

To decouple the model from the control, you'd have to have an observer of the model.  I would implement a `ProgressListener` inheriting `ActionListener`.  The model just notifies all registered `ProgressListener` that progress has been made.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MVCSwingWorkerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CalcModel      model      = new CalcModel();
        CalcView       view       = new CalcView();
        CalcController controller = new CalcController(model, view);
    }

    //Model class - contains long running methods ;)
    public static class CalcModel{

        //Contains registered progress listeners
        ArrayList<ActionListener> progressListeners = new ArrayList<ActionListener>();
        //Contains model's current progress
        public int status;

        //Takes in an instance of my control's Swing Worker
        public boolean longRunningProcess(MVCSwingWorkerExample.CalcController.Worker w){
            for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++){
                try {
                    //Silly calculation to publish some values
                    reportProgress( i==0 ? 0 : i*100/60);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Whowsa!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        //Notify all listeners that progress was made
        private void reportProgress(int i){
            status = i;
            ActionEvent e = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_FIRST, null);
            for(ActionListener l : progressListeners){
                l.actionPerformed(e);
            }
        }

        //Standard registering of the listeners
        public void addProgressListener(ActionListener l){
            progressListeners.add(l);
        }

        //Standard de-registering of the listeners
        public void removeProgressListener(ActionListener l){
            progressListeners.remove(l);
        }
    }

    //View Class - pretty bare bones (only contains view stuff)
    public static class CalcView{
        Box display;
        JButton actionButton;
        JLabel progress;

        public void buildDisplay(){
            display = Box.createVerticalBox();
            actionButton = new JButton("Press me!");
            display.add(actionButton);

            progress = new JLabel("Progress:");
            display.add(progress);
        }

        public void start(){
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(display);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static class CalcController{
        CalcModel model;
        CalcView view;

        public CalcController(CalcModel model, CalcView view){
            this.model = model;
            this.view = view;

            //Build the view
            view.buildDisplay();

            //Create an action to add to our view's button (running the swing worker)
            ActionListener buttonAction = new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Worker w = new Worker();
                    w.execute();
                }
            };
            view.actionButton.addActionListener(buttonAction);

            //Start up the view
            view.start();

        }

        //Notified when the Model updates it's status
        public class ProgressListener implements ActionListener{
            Worker w;

            public ProgressListener(Worker w){
                this.w = w;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CalcModel model = (CalcModel)e.getSource();
                w.publishValue(model.status);
            }

        }


        //The worker - usually part of the control
        public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Boolean, Integer>{

            public Worker(){
                //Register a listener to pay attention to the model's status
                CalcController.this.model.addProgressListener(new ProgressListener(this));
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
                //Call the model, and pass in this swing worker (so the model can publish updates)
                return model.longRunningProcess(this);
            }

            //Expose a method to publish results
            public void publishValue(int i){
                publish(i);
            }

              @Override
              protected void process(java.util.List<Integer> chunks){
                  view.progress.setText("Progress:" + chunks.get(chunks.size()-1) + "%");
              }

             @Override
               protected void done() {
                   try {
                       view.progress.setText("Done");
                   } catch (Exception ignore) {
                   }
               }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have thought of this already as a way not to do it. First of all it couples the model to the controller - secondly - what if model.doLongProcess() calls a method called foo.doLongProcess()-- we have to pass a reference to the swingWorker down the stack...

Comment: @volting ... fair enough.  In order to decouple the model from the control, you need to create an Observer for the model.  I recommend using an extension of the `ActionListener`.  I've updated the example to reflect your request.

Comment: why that additionally callback? Why not let model return intermediate chunks in doLongRunningTask and let the worker sit and wait for the next - something like the nio WatchService in jdk7? @volting feels like I'm still missing something ...

Answer (score 0):

For a long running process under Swing you must create a new Thread for that purpose, so when this process is complete, then you must update you MVC inside the "Swing thread", remember there is only one for each application.

Try find a way to let know the user that you application is processing, and do not allow him to "multiply" again, until done.

```
public class CalcController {

////////////////////////////////////////// inner class MultiplyListener
/**
 * When a mulitplication is requested. 1. Get the user input number from the
 * View. 2. Call the model to mulitply by this number. 3. Get the result
 * from the Model. 4. Tell the View to display the result. If there was an
 * error, tell the View to display it.
 */
class MultiplyListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        final String userInput = m_view.getUserInput();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    m_model.multiplyBy(userInput);
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfex) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            m_view.showError("Bad input: '" + userInput + "'");
                        }
                    });
                }
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        m_view.setTotal(m_model.getValue());
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();

    }
}//end inner class MultiplyListener

}
```